# Regex for Alpha Numeric and some special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, ember.js

I have a input controller which I want to allow only Alpha Numeric values and `-`,`@` and `#` special characters, I have using the following input-filter, `input-filter='[A-Za-z0-9 \-_@#]{1,20}'`, it is allowing but Alpha Numeric values properly but not allowing special characters, -,@ and #, what am I doing wrong, can somebody please help me - thanks a lot.

OK I have written a function for onKeyUp, as below, but what I want is to remove those special characters that are not from the 3 in the above list -, @, #.
Can you please modify the function how can I remove them automatically? Or suggest me for something. Thanks in advance my friend,
JS function:

```
forTest(e) {
                e = 'some test';
            },
```

Ember Control (html input-tag control):

```
                            {{#tag-input
                            tags=tags
                            addTag=(action 'addTag')
                            onKeyUp=(action 'forTest')
                            removeTagAtIndex=(action 'removeTagAtIndex')
                            as |tag|
                            }}
                            {{tag}}
                            {{/tag-input}}
```

Comment: It actually works https://regex101.com/r/tgME2R/1.

Comment: It might be advantageous to add anchors around your regex `^<regex>$`. Please post your source code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape some special characters. You wrote  `-_`, which matches any char in the range from ' ' (Space) to '_'. Here is the escaped version:
`[A-Za-z0-9\ \-_@#]{1,20}`. One tip: You can always "debug" your RegExes with [this](https://www.regextester.com/) tool

Comment: He seemed to escape the dash already `[A-Za-z0-9 \-_@#]{1,20}` maybe the escape needs to be escaped if it is a non-html, JS string.

Comment: No it didn't help, still it is not allowing me to enter special characters that I wanted like -, @, #

Comment: Actually I found the problem is not with the input-filter, it is with the mask value,     mask='********************', how can I change this mask value to accept the alpha numeric with those 3 special characters?